# How to use single line installation for Kinetic

Tags: ros, installation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation/TwoLineInstall, I'm told that I'm able to install ROS by using this command

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oroca/oroca-ros-pkg/master/ros_install.sh | bash -s %NAME_CATKIN_WS% %NAME_ROS_DISTRO_LOWERCASE%

(e.g.)
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oroca/oroca-ros-pkg/master/ros_install.sh | bash -s cws_oroca kinetic
```

My question is, what does `%NAME_CATKIN_WS%` mean? I can guess that `%NAME_ROS_DISTRO_LOWERCASE%` is substituted with the ros version I wish to download (e.g. Kinetic), but what about `%NAME_CATKIN_WS%`? Is it the name of the directory I want to use to store my work? (e.g. ~/catkin_ws)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288165/how-to-use-single-line-installation-for-kinetic/) by [Frank Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/31663/frank-lee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For context, the single install is running a shell script which essentially mimics the steps in [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment) tutorial for installing & configuring ROS (it isn't exactly the same, but close enough).

To answer your question: Yes, the single install script is just going to create a folder named %NAME_CATKIN_WS%, initialize it as a catkin workspace, run catkin_make, and source it for your ROS environment. This folder / workspace is where you'll create and build your own ros packages (or where you could build existing packages from source). The [catkin tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials) are definitely worth going through to get a conceptual understanding of the role of the catkin_ws in development.

---

Originally posted by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) with karma: 929 on 2018-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1